# Store array of model types

Tags: extjs

Ext.Store can contain an array of types of models?

logic :

```
var myStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    model: ['User3','User']
});
```

It's possible?

Comment: can you post the code of User3 and User model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cant do that, but you can have similar effect bu creating a new model lets say `User4` which contains all the fields from `User` and `User3`.

So to illustrate this

```
    Ext.define("Model", {
        extend: "Ext.data.Model",
        fields: ["name1", "name2"]
    });

    Ext.define("Model1", {
        extend: "Ext.data.Model",
        fields: ["name1"]
    });

    Ext.define("Model2", {
        extend: "Ext.data.Model",
        fields: ["name2"]
    });

    var store = Ext.create("Ext.data.Store", {
        model: "Model"
    });

    var model1 = Ext.create("Model1", { name1: "Name 1" });
    var model2 = Ext.create("Model2", { name1: "Name 2" });

    store.add(model1);
    store.add(model2);
```

Here is the [demo](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/b0e). You can also make `Model1` or `Model2` from `Model` data like this:

```
    store.each(function(record) {
       console.log(record); 
       if (record.data.name1 != "")
          console.log(Ext.create("Model1", record.data));
       else
          console.log(Ext.create("Model2", record.data)); 
    });
```